# QGIS Export ESRI File Geodatabase versus ESRI FileGDB

Tags: qgis-3, file-geodatabase

Ive just noticed in QGIS (v3.28.11) that on the "Save Vector Layer As" format options, that there are two ESRI File Geodatabase options.

One is called

```
ESRI File Geodatabase
```

The other is called

```
ESRI FileGDB
```

[image]

There are more 'Layer Options' available on the `ESRI File Geodatabase` selection.
The assumption is that the `ESRI File Geodatabase` option is the 'official' writer, whilst the `ESRI FileGDB` is the OpenFileGDB type, however Im not sure.

Can someone please confirm which is which and, if there are any issues in using one of them?

Comment: I do not have the same on version 3.34 .

Comment: @GforGIS - can you confirm how it is listed in 3.34?

Comment: Maybe you can guess the drivers by comparing the save options with the document pages https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/openfilegdb.html and https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/filegdb.html#vector-filegdb.

Comment: @user30184 yep this gives the answer, feel free to put that in the answer section and ill edit it/tidy it up for you and accept it.

Comment: Please write the answer yourself because you know all the details now.